# OpenShift Resource Locale Set to en_US - Resources NOT Found

Tags: java, resources, openshift, locale, struts-1

I am moving a Struts 1.3.10 webapp to OpenShift.

To get started I have moved just the login page stuff to OpenShift. It works perfectly on my development machine but on OpenShift, the login page input field labels show like this:

**???en_US.label.login???**

The labels are in a resource file called MessageResources.properties.

I tried creating a resource file called MessageResources_en_US.properties but it made no difference.

I also tried this:

```
rhc env-set -a testdb LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8
```

But that made no difference either.

Any ideas?

I know it's something to do with locale...

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to move MessageResources.properties from /src/main/**java** to /src/main/**resources**.

Simples...